# In port/adapter (onion) architecture, can I have domain if there is no persistence in the application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, onion-architecture

I have a microservice application with presumably port/adapter(onion) architecture. The layers layout: domain --> application --> infrastructure --> web. The application mainly exchanges the data between web and infrastructure layers. For example, an object is posted through web layer, and then this object is sent(post) to an inventory through infrastructure layer after some processing in application layer. The web layer uses Dto. Does it make sense to have domain layer and the following transformations: web Dto ---map to---> domain objects (for processing in application layer) ---map to---> infrastructure Dto and sent to inventory?

Comment: I see nothing wrong. Infact the Spring data Rest almost achieves the onion architecture by just exposing via interfaces and loose coupling. Having said that, it can be a question in Stack overflow. :)

Comment: I was thinking of just passing dtos from web layer to application layer and therefore no domain layer required. This avoids additional efforts in transformation. However, this might not be a good practice but I am not sure so I asked if you guys shed light on this. :)

Comment: Alright :) If you need to avoid additional overhead of transforming you can either use the entity objects as DTO itself. :) again I say it in reference with spring-data-rest. so no extra DTO mapping is required and the communication is via entities as dto directly .

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am using swagger documentation too. If I use just domain or entity objects in all layers, then I need to put swagger annotations on domain objects. This contradicts the fact that domain layer should not be dependent on external frameworks, in this case swagger. Domain should as pure as possible. ;)

Comment: Yeah . Spring Data Rest uses HATEOS which rises to the fact that REST API itself is the documentation. Swagger couples to the domain and thus any change to the domain and API needs continuous documentation change and needs to be updated. And if you have a major release that changes whole API, you are forced to modify.

Comment: Do you mean it is fine to use swagger annotations (i.e ApiModelProperty) inside domain (entity) classes if I use entity object directly in outer layer (web layer)?

Comment: It's fine just that in HATEOS, the API is itself the documentation. It gives you references and linkes to other entities and more API details. If you have used HATEOS or Spring data rest, you will get more knowledge.